# Catenative Clause and Canonical Clause

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Consider the following sentence -

> She was working.

[Function] Subject: *She* [Category: Noun Phrase]  and 
[Function] Predicate: *was working* [Category: Verb Phrase]

Now consider the verb phrase - *was working*. It has an auxiliary verb - *was* - and a lexical verb - *work*. So here also, as far as my understanding (which is based on The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language page no 1209), we can analyze it like the following -

> [[Vaux *WAS*] [Catenative Clause [*WORKING*]]

**1.** Now is my understanding correct? 
**2.** If it is, then it consists of a subordinate clause (I am referring to the Catenative clause). Then how can this sentence be a Canonical Clause? 
[The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language on page no 46, markes this sentence as Canonical Clause]

Comment: A canonical clause has to be positive, active, and main. "He was working" is a main clause, so it's a canonical clause. The non-canonical clause is the gerund-participial clause "working". Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes: CGEL treats "was working" as aux + catenative complement. It meets CGEL's criteria for a canonical clause by virtue of being a declarative, positive, non-coordinate, main clause not belonging to any of the information-packaging constructions (passive, _it_-cleft etc)

Comment: @BillJ And subordinate, too.

Comment: Only the catenative clause is subordinate. The matrix clause is a main clause.

Comment: @BillJ *nods* but then the matrix clause can not be a Canonical clause, right?

Comment: Yes, it can. There's nothing to say that a canonical clause cannot be a matrix clause (i.e. one that contains an embedded sub clause).

Comment: @Araucaria CGEL are saying it's just the underlined subordinate clause in that example that is non-canonical. See ex [1] ii a. for what MFI is asking about.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, yes. I see. Quite right!

Comment: Maybe you could write your own answer now, and then we could upvote it?

Comment: @Araucaria please give me some time. I will.

Answer (score 1):

> She was working.

[Function] Subject: *She* [Category: Noun Phrase]  and 
[Function] Predicate: *was working* [Category: Verb Phrase]

Inside this Verb Phrase, *was* is the auxiliary verb and it takes a Catenative clause as complement. The Cetenative Clause is realized by the Gerand-Participle form of the lexical verb - *work*. This clause has no explicit subject but it is implied. This Catenative Clause is subordinate to the matrix clause - *she was working*.

This answers question no. 1

Whether a clause is Canonical or not depends on a number of syntactic features, namely -

- **Polarity** (*Whether the clause is positive or negative* - if the clause is positive, it is Canonical and if it is negative, it is non-canonical.)
- **Clause Type** (*Whether the clause is declarative or anything else for example Interrogative or imperative or anything else* - if the clause is declarative, it is canonical. Else it is non-canonical)
- **Subordination** (*Whether the clause is subordinate or main clause* - if the clause is main clause, it is canonical. And if it is subordinate clause, it is non-canonical.)
- **Coordination** (*Whether a clause is marked by a coordinator or not* - Canonical clauses are non-coordinate but non-canonical clauses are coordinate. Ex: *That is Bill or I'm blind*. Here *That is Bill* and *I'm blind* is Canonical but the whole sentence is non-canonical.)
- **Information Packaging** (*Information can be packaged in a variety of ways like PASSIVE, PREPOSING, EXPTRAPOSING etc* - Canonical clauses expresses are most elementary ones. If the clause is passive, preposed or extraposed etc, they are non-canonical)

These features can be combined in case of non-canonical clauses.

Ex: Jim says that he is not well.

The canonical clause is *Jim says that he is not well*, but *that he is not well* is non-canonical due to two features mentioned above - Polarity and Subordination.

Now in our case

> She was working.

It is a canonical clause, but the subjectless Gerund-Participle clause - *working* - is a non-canonical clause.